# Maximal Square with 0 inside

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

The question Maximal Square in https://leetcode.com/problems/maximal-square/description/ is easy to solve by DP. But how to solve the following up question:

Similar as Maximal Square question, but allows 0's inside a square, **"inside" means the border of the square must be all 1**.
For example, given the following matrix:

1 0 1 0 0

1 0 1 1 1

1 1 1 0 1

1 0 1 1 1

Return 9.

**Update: Because the 3*3 matrix in the right bottom corner matches the requirement, the border must be all 1, and there can be 0 inside the square.**

I thought up a O(n^3) algorithm: take `maze[i][j]` as the right bottom corner of the square if `maze[i][j] == 1`, enumerate the edge length of the square. If edge length is 3, consider whether `maze[i - 2][j - 2]`, `maze[i][j - 2]`, `maze[i - 2][j]`, `maze[i][j]` forms a square with the numbers in each edge are all 1.

Is there any better algorithm?

Comment: In your example, can't you take any 4x4 square? I.e. a square that just fits in. This gives the answer 16. What exactly do you mean by "allow 0's inside the square"?

Comment: How many 0s are allowed? otherwise, the biggest square is always the answer.

Comment: @Henry I have updated the question.

Comment: @PhamTrung The edge of the square must be composed by 1, and 0 can be inside of the square. I have updated the description of the question

Comment: For O(n^3) you have to pre-calculate some data to check that edges contain only ones quickly. Not sure that we can do better than O(n^3) here.

Comment: Several claim that it can be done in O(n^2) or O(n^2 log n) [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-matrix-o-x-find-largest-subsquare-surrounded-x/), would need to test them if they are correct. One of them is replacing the 0s surrounded by 1s for 1s and then running the original DP algorithm

Comment: @juvian Thanks for you comment. I did not find the O(n^2) or O(n^2 log n) in the GeeksforGeeks link, can you provide more information?

Comment: @YingjieLiu they are in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved in **O (n * m)** time and space complexity, where **n** is total rows and **m** is total columns in matrix. You may look at the code below where I have commented out to make it understandable.
Please, let me know if you have any doubt.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void precalRowSum(vector< vector<int> >& grid, vector< vector<int> >&rowSum, int n, int m) {
// contiguous sum upto jth position in ith row
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     int sum = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
          if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
              sum++;
          } else {
              sum = 0;
          }
          rowSum[i][j] = sum;
      }
   }
 }

 void precalColSum(vector< vector<int> >& grid, vector< vector<int> >&colSum, int n, int m) {
// contiguous sum upto ith position in jth column
for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
            sum++;
        } else {
            sum = 0;
        }
        colSum[i][j] = sum;
     }
   }
 }

int solve(vector< vector<int> >& grid, int n, int m) {  
  vector< vector<int> >rowSum(n, vector<int>(m, 0));
  vector< vector<int> >colSum(n, vector<int>(m, 0));
  // calculate rowwise sum for 1
  precalRowSum(grid, rowSum, n, m);
  // calculate colwise sum for 1
  precalColSum(grid, colSum, n, m);
  vector< vector<int> >zerosHeight(n, vector<int>(m, 0));
  int ans = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        zerosHeight[i][j] = ( grid[i][j] == 0 );
        if (grid[i][j] == 0 && i > 0) {
            zerosHeight[i][j] += zerosHeight[i - 1][j];
        }
    }
    if (i == 0) continue;
    // perform calculation on ith row
    for (int j = 1; j < m; ) {
        int height = zerosHeight[i][j];
        if (!height) {
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        int cnt = 0;
        while (j < m && height ==  zerosHeight[i][j]) {
            j++;
            cnt++;
        }
        if ( j == m) break;
        if (cnt == height && (i - cnt) >= 0 ) {
            // zeros are valid, now check validity for boundries
            // Check validity of upper boundray, lower boundary, left boundary, right boundary respectively
            if (rowSum[i - cnt][j] >= (cnt + 2) && rowSum[i + 1][j] >= (cnt + 2) &&
                colSum[i + 1][j - cnt - 1] >= (cnt + 2) && colSum[i + 1][j] >= (cnt + 2) ){
                ans = max(ans, (cnt + 2) * (cnt + 2) );
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return ans;
}
int main() {
 int n, m;
 cin>>n>>m;
 vector< vector<int> >grid;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    vector<int>tmp;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        int x;
        cin>>x;
        tmp.push_back(x);
    }
    grid.push_back(tmp);
 }
 cout<<endl;

 cout<< solve(grid, n, m) <<endl;
 return 0;
}
```